# " Gtk-WARNING: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine" error while installing Adobe air installation on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: gtk, air, adobe, gtk2, ubuntu-13.10

Hi I'm new to Ubuntu and I need to install Adobe Air on my computer! I have Ubuntu 13.10 version.

I have followed the following steps:

1. `$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386`
2. I have downloaded Adobe Air (http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/lin/download/2.6/AdobeAIRInstaller.bin)
3. `$ chmod +x AdobeAIRInstaller.bin`
4. `$ ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin`

At this point I had the error message:

```
  Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
  Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
  (setup:3193): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
  Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

5- After looking different website I've done this:

```
  $ sudo apt-get install --reinsta gtk2-engines
  $ sudo apt-get install gtk-murrine-engine gtk-equinox-engine
```

and I got back this error message for the last command:

> E: Unable to locate package gtk-murrine-engine
> E: Unable to locatepackage gtk-equinox-engine

So I don't know anymore what else to do, can anyone help me please?

Comment: Have you tried installing the engines for the other architecture? e.g. 64 bit if you're on a 32 bit machine, and vice versa? Because that is what I had to do when I ran into this same problem. The software I was running was 32 bit and my machine and OS is 64 bit. Thus I had to install the gtk2-eninge.i696 and gtk-murrine-engine.i686 even though I had the .x86_64 version of those packages installed. Good luck.

Comment: [This askubuntu page could be related/cross-site-duplicated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774664/gtk-warning-unable-to-locate-theme-engine-in-module-path-adwaita-error-o)

Answer (score 23):

Installing the following will fix ..

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-*
sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2.4-1c2
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

if that doesn't work then try ..

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines:i386
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-*:i386
sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2.4-1c2:i386
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even the second commands group did not help on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, despite installing a lot of stuff for me. You can revert it with `sudo apt remove gtk2-engines gtk2-engines-* libgtkmm-2.4-1c2 libcanberra-gtk-module gtk2-engines:i386 gtk2-engines-*:i386 libgtkmm-2.4-1c2:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386`

Answer (score 7):

I had this same issue and solved it by just installing this DEB package: **gtk2-engines-murrine**

On a 32-bit Linux operating system with APT package manager, all you have to do to install that package is to run this command on the Linux shell:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine
```

My system is a 64-bit XUbuntu Linux, version 16.04 "Xenial Xerus". If your system is 64-bit just like mine (and uses APT as package manager), then run this supercommand:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 ; sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
```

- Note: on the supercommand above, the first command (left side) adds 32-bit packge support for your 64-bit system, while the second command (right side) installs the 32-bit package on your 64-bit system.

Comment: `sudo eopkg it gtk2-engine-murrine` worked for me (on Solus)

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2.4-1c2
```

This resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Perfect. I've been getting these errors for over a year. Finally set about this morning to fix it and there it is! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the ***overlay-scrollbar-gtk2*** and ***unity-gtk2-module*** 
packages.
The following installation resolved the problem for me :

```
sudo apt-get install overlay-scrollbar-gtk2 unity-gtk2-module
```

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-*
sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2.4-1c2
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

But it gives the same error. After that I download [murrine-0.90.3.tar.gz](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=download%20murrine-0.90.3.tar.gz&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and install it.To do that

```
tar -xvf murrine-0.90.3.tar.gz
cd murrine-0.90.3
./configure
make 
make install
```

After that ,I run `./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin` and it works for me.Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Good idea, but `./configure` gives me `configure: error: GTK+-2.12 is required to compile murrine` which I wasn't able to solve. I did `sudo apt-get install intltool` before. Revert with `sudo apt remove gtk2-engines gtk2-engines-* libgtkmm-2.4-1c2 libcanberra-gtk-module intltool`